# Complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I have a recursive algorithm like :

```
int alg(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 2;
  for (int i = 0; i<= n-1; ++i)
    alg(i);
}
```

Obviously the `n == 0` case is `Θ(1)`. However I am having trouble understanding how it really works. I mean it must be something like :

```
T(n) = T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-1).
```

And then we have to give `T(1), T(2), .., T(n-1) = xT(0)`. I can understand the way it goes for n=0 and n=1, but for bigger n it goes wrong.

Comment: looks O(aragh!) to me. I wouldn't know how to analyse it properly, but it looks to be related to O(n!), which is about as bad as it gets.

Answer (score 15):

You can observe that:

```
T(n)     = T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-2) + T(n-1)
T(n - 1) = T(0) + T(1) + ... + T(n-2)
```

Therefore

```
T(n)     = 2 * T(n-1)
```

At this point, we can conclude that the complexity is O(2<sup>n</sup>). Actually, it is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).